# can I have multiple docker compose yaml files in same directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can I keep multiple docker-compose.yml files in same directory? e.g.

i want docker-compose-1.yml with some services and docker-compose-2.yml with some other services.
Is there any requirement to have specific file names and what is the command used to start it ?

```
docker-compose up --build -f docker-compose-1.yml ??
```

this results in

```
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can keep indeed multiple `docker-compose` files with different names(they can be completely custom) in the same directory and start them all at the same time.

Try this:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose1.yml -f docker-compose2.yml up --build
```

The `-f` arguements should be before the `up` and then `--build` after.

Please note  that in the case of many docker compose files these files are merged, check here for more info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files

Comment: do multiple compose files make sense? let us say dev version has nginx redis postgres and express api, and prod version only has api and nginx because it uses elasticache and rds? Should you make multiple docker compose files in this scenawrio?

Comment: Yes sometimes, having multiple docker compose files makes sense. One of these cases would be to target different environments as you mention(dev, stage, prod etc)

Answer (score 6):

You can run the services in multiple docker-compose files using parameter `-p`

**`-p, --project-name NAME`**

So, the following command should work:

```
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-new.yml -p new_project_name up -d
```

[See this parameter at docs.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name)

Also you can use variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` in an `.env` file, such as file `env.sample`, as below:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=sample_project
```

And use this .env file in your  command as below:

```
docker-compose --env-file env.sample -f ./docker-compose-new.yml up -d
```

Note that your containers will be named like your project name, e.g. `sample_project-service_one`

Just this!